# Mapbox style on webpage

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to change the position/style of map. However, I can only position it from the top-left of the page or table. Is there a way to adjust the position of the map of my webpage to have it better wrap around any other information on a webpage(center it, make it's position relative, etc.) such as text or images?

I tried adjusting the style of the map itself, doing things like setting the position to relative or setting the top/bottom margins to auto. However, when I do that, the map disappears from the screen. There is a not-so-noticeable line where the map should be when this alteration occurs.
I also tried altering the style of the map container where the map div is located within, but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this through the use of an iframe, where I create a separate page with only the map and I insert that webpage into where I want. The iframe looks like this:

```
<iframe src="map.html" title="mapbox"></iframe>
```

and the <map.html> is a page that only displays the map using the mapbox api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).